# Password is not being Saved in SSIS for Oracle based Connection Manager

Tags: oracle, ssis, connection

My problem is , I am talking to Oracle database from my SSIS package. The Connection Manager is not saving Password and it fails on Run time. I have changed it and tried to use XML based Config file to store connection string. I have manually updated Connection string in Config file and added Password=[Something] but it's still not working.

Can anyone please advise me to solve this puzzle

Thanks,

Comment: You mention you have changed to an XML config file, are you then saving this connection to a variable within the SSIS package? Also have you changed the connection to use an expression based on the variable?

Comment: Added a Variable at package level and setting connection string through that variable but it's still not picking up Password.

Comment: Did you try setting the protection level property to `DontSaveSensitive`?